# How to save python ml model so that in can be run in C# Unity

Tags: python, c#, unity-game-engine, machine-learning

I have a python script that trains an ml model. I would like to then export this model so that it can be loaded and used in a Unity game written in C#.

I know I can't serialize the model using pickle or scikit-learn's joblib because they are not supported by C#. So is there any way to save the model so that it can be deserialised and used in my Unity game?

Comment: You may want to explore onnx: https://onnx.ai/

Comment: What kind of ML Model?

Comment: It will be a scikit-learn model, most likely LDA.